# Mysql directory path in ubuntu 20.04 tls

Tags: apache2, mysql, backup, phpmyadmin

I have a backup of a database that is more than 500MB and I need to restore on a server, but every time phpMyAdmin give me error.

I want to restore it by uploading the file in my server then from terminal move it to `/mysql/data/` folder, but I don’t know the path for MySQL.

I changed PHP 7.3’s `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` to 1000MB, but still have a problem when importing the database.

I have installed cyberpanel on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS machine and want to upload the SQL dump. I received an error each time I tried to upload via the browser:

[image]

and the other one is:

[image]

Also, I have many databases in there, I found this command [based on this tutorial](https://support.solarwinds.com/SuccessCenter/s/article/Back-up-and-restore-the-MySQL-database-using-the-command-line?language=en_US):

```
mysql -u root -p[my_root_password] [mydatabase] < mydatabase.sql
```

This does not help me because I have serious questions:

1. My database is under the domain name and there are lots of db on the server, how should I find the correct name?

   [image]
2. I have uploaded the file to my server, at the end of the command is `< mydatabase.sql`. I don't know how to state which database to import the data dump to.

I'm so confused…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no need to write the SQL file directly to the MySQL directory. If you have the SQL dump in an uncompressed format, you can do something like this:

```
sudo mysql {database_name} < {sql_file}
```

**Notes:**

1. Unless you have drastically modified your MySQL installation, you can connect as `root` just by using `sudo mysql`
2. the name of the database is the last item in the connection string
3. the SQL file must be in an uncompressed, readable format

So, if you are importing a file named `shopwood.sql` into the `high_shopwood` database, you would do this:

```
sudo mysql high_shopwood < shopwood.sql
```

This can be done with each database that you are migrating.